# Apart from client coding help, what is the benefit of '!!' operator in Kotlin if it throws NPE when the object is null?

Tags: java, kotlin

Kotlin has very beautiful null checks in compile time itself.

Suppose a scenario like below:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Please enter a number: ")
    var num = readLine()!!.toInt()
    println("Entered number is $num")
}
```

If the user do not enter any value or any Int the code will throw a NPE.
Instead if '?.' i.e. null-safe is used there will be no exception thrown (null value will be replied though).

I have gone through this [blog](https://medium.com/@agrawalsuneet/safe-calls-vs-null-checks-in-kotlin-f7c56623ab30). But apart from being a help for the client to code does this operator '!!' have other benefits?

Comment: !! is not a null check

Answer (score 7):

In this example, there is no benefit in using !!. In other contexts, !! can be used if you know that a value is not going to be null and you don't want to write more verbose code for handling the null case.

Consider this example:

```
enum class A { Foo, Bar }

val aNames = mapOf(A.Foo to "Foo", A.Bar to "Bar")

fun printName(a: A) {
    val x: String = aNames[a]!!
}
```

In this example, the map is guaranteed to have a value for the given key, because `A` is an `enum class`, and you have initialized the map with all possible values for it. However, the compiler does not recognize that, because `Map.get` returns a nullable type for any map. In this case, you can still write:

```
val x = aNames[a]
if (x == null) { ... }
```

However, the condition will never be true, and it does not make sense to write code to handle an impossible condition. Therefore, you can simply tell the compiler that the condition is impossible, by using the !! operator.

Comment: But if I follow this code it will throw NPE. Instead if checks be there like if(obj != null){ obj.doSomething()}, at least there won't be any exception thrown. My curiosity is to know where it actually works if not here.

Comment: If you know from the flow of the program that `obj` is not going to be null, then writing the `if (obj != null)` check is simply unnecessary code.

Comment: " Instead if checks be there like if(obj != null){ obj.doSomething()}" If you want this behavior, use `obj?.doSomething()`.

Answer (score 3):

> Kotlin has very beautiful null checks in compile time itself.

Checks at compile time aren't null-checks, but *nullability* checks. If you declare a value as nullable, then the compiler makes sure you can't dereference it. If you add a runtime null-check, the compiler notices this and smart-casts your value into a non-nullable type.

> apart from being a help for the client to code does this operator '!!' have other benefits?

The `!!` operator fully justifies itself as a shortcut to a null-check and a throw-statement. That's a big benefit to have.

The compiler has no superpowers and cannot turn null-unsafe code into null-safe code. This goes especially for calls into the null-unsafe Java library.